# vb.net timer does not stop when calling .Stop()

Tags: vb.net, timer

I am trying to run 2 background workers not at once but when one is done then start the other and I am using a timer

Code :

```
If CheckBox1.Checked = True And OpenOfficeDone = False Then
     OpenOffice.RunWorkerAsync()
     workTmr.Stop()
End If
If CheckBox2.Checked = True And ZipDone = False Then
      Zip.RunWorkerAsync()
      workTmr.Stop()
 End If
```

and in the background workers i have this code to start the timer again:

```
   If (Not Zip.IsBusy) Then
        ZipDone = True
        workTmr.Start()
    End If
```

And

```
    If (Not OpenOffice.IsBusy) Then
        OpenOfficeDone = True
        workTmr.Start()
    End If
```

But when I run it then the background workers run at once.

Comment: you dont need 2 background workers, just perform the tasks sequentially; the RunWorkerCompleted event would tell you when either of them is done and I am not sure a Timer does what you think it does

Comment: Please explain a little better than "I am trying to run 2 background workers not at once but when one is done then start the other and I am using a timer". It's really difficult to guess what you mean. Also please show complete code - including timer & background worker declarations and set up - enough for us to copy and paste and reproduce your issue.

Comment: You probably need only one timer-driven routine which, each time the timer goes off, decides which one of two things it ought to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried .Enabled = True/False